# Whats the safest way to submit a page to itself?

Tags: php, html

what is the safest thing to put in the

`<form action="">`

to submit the form to the current page?

Comment: Do not forget to set the `method` attribute to either GET or POST. It is a must.

Comment: Is there any safest? POST is invisible to the human eyes, GET is visible visible. If someone wants to sniffer it, he will. The only safe i see is under https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put nothing here. action is default page by default

Answer (score 2):

It's best to just omit the action attribute entirely.

Comment: I think ommiting the action attribute is not valid html - or not?

Comment: I just tried validating a page which omits the action attribute and it validates well in HTML5.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i didn't check it as HTML5. As XHTML 1.0 Transitional/Strict though it does not validate